# facebook prophet predict value at fixed date in the future

Tags: time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I want to do something like:

```py
predicted_value = Prophet.predict_some_value('2020-12-12 14:47:00')
```

where the date is some future date and produce only one value.

Is there a way to predict only the value at a certain date in the future using Facebook Prophet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer after reading the documentation more carefully.

First we need to generate a DataFrame containing the date we want to predict the value for:

```py
future_date = pd.DataFrame({'ds':['2020-08-15 7:55:30']})
```

Then just use the predict method of the fitted model:

```py
forecast = my_model.predict(future_date)
```

Comment: is there a way to backfill using Prophet ? i.e. get prediction values for previous week ?